# How do I get data in subcollection from filtered document in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

```
    let db = admins.firestore();
    let filter = JSON.stringify(req.body.foodid);
    **db.collection("AllFood").where("foodid","==",filter).collection("Ingredient")**.get().then(foodmenus => {res.send('{"STATUS":"SUCCESS","data":' + JSON.stringify(foodmenus.docs.map(doc => doc.data())) + '}');
```

How do I get the Ingredient collection that belongs to the "foodid" of document in collection "AllFood".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make the assumption that your query returns a unique document. Since queries in Firestore are shallow, you need to first get the Document corresponding to the query, and then query all the Documents in the `Ingredient` sub-collection of this Document, as follows:

```
let db = admin.firestore();
let filter = JSON.stringify(req.body.foodid);
db.collection("AllFood").where("foodid", "==", filter)
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        const docSnapshot = snapshot.docs[0];  //The first (and unique) doc returned by the query
        return docSnapshot.ref.collection("Ingredient").get();
    })
    .then(foodmenus => {
        res.send('{"STATUS":"SUCCESS","data":' + JSON.stringify(foodmenus.docs.map(doc => doc.data())) + '}');
    })
```